# Event when consumer acked message

Tags: rabbitmq

Is there any event provided by RabbitMQ or by some plugins which will "fired" when consumer acked message?
The result of event for example can be message to specific queue or webhook.
Any solutions or recomendations?

Expected scenario: there is a queue with messages for client app 
- app consumes message from this queue
- app sends lightweight AMQP `ack` packet
- server receives `ack`
- server calls some sort of callback (webhook)

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily achieved from the consumer side as well , when you `ack` the message from the consumer , call the external webhook from the consumer itself. The message body can carry the webhook URL which can then be parsed at the consumer side , this way you will have the flexibility to pass in parameters specific to the message.

Comment: I want to avoid this type of traffic to be generated on client side. So, "external webhook" have to be called by server when it receives `ack` from client.

Comment: As of now there is no way to trap this at the broker end.... :-(

Comment: Yes, this is the best solution. The consumer should either do the work itself, or publish an "acked" message to RabbitMQ.